# Dynamically compare types in java

Tags: java, casting

I have a Screen class, which is the base class of several kind of screens, eg PauseScreen, MainScreen, etc.

I have a stack of screens in my classes, and my game is pushing / poping screens depending on the buttons.

But I need to jump from one screen to another ( popping everything until the needed screen ).

Lets say I have a MainScreen, a GameScreen and a PauseScreen. I need to go from PauseScreen to MainScreen, ( popping PauseScreen and GameScreen ).

What is the prefered way to do it in java? I could store an id in each screens but it doesn't seems right.

Edit : This is what I want to achieve, I was just curious to know is there was a better way that would not require creating an enum ( IIRC it is possible to get the type of the class at runtime, but maybe it is a bad practice for what I want to do? ).

```
class X
{
    Stack< Screen > screens = new Stack< Screen >();

    void push( Screen s )
    {
        screens.push( s );
    }

    void pop()
    {
        screens.pop();
    }

    void popUntil( Screen.Type t )
    {
        // go through the list in reverse order
        while( screens.next().type != t )
            screens.pop();
    }
}

// other places in the code

app.popUntil( Screen.Type.MainScreen );
app.popUntil( Screen.Type.GameScreen );
```

Comment: Primarily opinion based!, example use instanceof or you Screen's can implement and interface with method int getTypeOfScreen(), the preferred way?? your way!!!

Comment: Of course I could just do it and move on, but since I am new with the language, I first wanted to see if there was better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Your quest is legit, but without knowing your exact code, it gets very hard to answer "prefered way", I probably would have preferred a common interface and call a public int getType() with a nice switch statement... Then what is preferred?, the fastest, the most readable, the shortest code.... or the way you know best??

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: You have some nice answers below, can't really understand the use of Stack probably a Map would be faster... but again the preferred way is yours.. I can suggest this web site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly refer to classes using the `.class` operator, which returns a `java.lang.Class` instance:

```
class X
{
    // ...

    void popUntil(Class<? extends Screen.Type> type)
    {
        // go through the list in reverse order
        while( screens.next().getClass() != type)
        {
            screens.pop();
        }
    }
}

x.popUntil(Screen.Type.MainScreen.class);
x.popUntil(Screen.Type.GameScreen.class);
```

Note that instances of `java.lang.Class` can be compared using reference equality (`==` and `!=`) rather than object equality (`equals` method). However, this implementation checks only if the type of the instance is exactly the given argument. If you want to check if `extends` or `implements` it, you can use the `java.lang.Class#isInstance(Object)` method:

```
while (!type.isInstance(screens.next()))
{
    screens.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `instanceof` operator

```
Screen screen = stack.pop();
if (screen instanceof PauseScreen) {

}
else if (screen instanceof MainScreen) {

}
else if (screen instanceof GameScreen) {

}
else if (/*...*/) {
    //...
}
else {
    otherStack.push(screen);
}
```

Comment: This would work with something like popUntil( new MainScreen() ), but I would like to not send an instance of the class. ( I do not have access to any of the screens outside the class that owns the stack.

Comment: @Aulaulz you can only call a method or use a field of an instance you have access to.  No access means you can't do anything to that instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `instanceof` operator for this kind of purpose:

```
if(someObject instanceof SomeType)
{
    SomeType cast = (SomeType) someObject;
    //do stuff with cast
}
```

There's a section in this tutorial about this topic: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good candidate for the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

```
public interface ScreenVisitor {
    void visitMain(MainScreen screen);
    void visitGame(GameScreen screen);
    void visitPause(PauseScreen screen);
}

public class VisitorForStuff implements ScreenVisitor {
    void visitMain(MainScreen screen) {
        // do stuff for MainScreen
     }
     // etc.
}

public abstract class Screen {
    ...
    public abstract void visit(ScreenVisitor visitor);
    ...
}

public class GameScreen extends Screen {       
    ...
    public void visit(ScreenVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitGame(this);
    }
    ...
}

...
Screen screen = stack.pop()
screen.visit(new VisitorForStuff());
...
```

The Visitor uses a double-dispatch mechanism to allow for type-safe downcasting without the use of instanceof and casting. Although there's not a huge difference from using `instanceof` in a particular case, it's quite a flexible pattern - allowing for many different types of Visitor implementations - and it cane highlights uses through compile-time errors, so when you create a new implementation of Screen, you can extend the Visitor interface and quickly find all the places which will need to be updated to handle visiting the new type of Screen.